# Suppose that $f: \mathbf{R} \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ is a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f: \mathbf{R} \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ is a continuous function and that $U \subseteq \mathbf{R}$ is open.  Prove that $$f \space \overleftarrow{} \space (U) = \{x \in \mathbf{R} : f(x)\in U\}$$ is an open set. Show by example that if $V$ is open, then $$f(V) = \{y \in \mathbf{R} : y=f(x) \space \mbox{for some} \space x\in V\}$$ need not be open.

The proof should follow from starting with a set U that is open in the reals.  But I am unsure how the proof brings the open set and the continuity of the fuction together to prove that the set is open.

Comment: Are you using the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity for $f$? (or Perhaps sequential continuity?)

Comment: What is your definition of continuity? In many cases, being the inverse image of an open set is the definition of continuity.

Comment: Hint: For any $y \in U$, there exists some $\epsilon > 0$ such that the open interval centered at $y$ of radius $\epsilon$ is contained in $U$. Using the definition of continuity of $f$, show that the preimage of this open interval is a union of open intervals.

Answer (score 1):

For the first one, you should be able to work out an epsilon/delta argument. As a way of seeing the big picture, it's a theorem that if $f$ is a continuous function, the inverse image of an open set is open. Part one is a direct consequence. And you can prove that the inverse of an open set is open from the epsilon/delta definition of continuity.

For the second one, you can get a counterexample from the simplest function you can possibly think of that isn't the identity function.